# Filtering an array of Maybe (nullable) types in Flow to remove null values

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, flowtype

I have an array of Maybe (nullable) type, I want to filter those `null`'s to have an array containing only non-null values:

```
@flow

type Foo = {
  foo: string
}

const bar: Array<?Foo> = [ null, { foo: 'Qux' } ]

const baz = bar
  .filter(x => x != null)
  .map(({ foo }) => foo);
```

However, flow complains that the argument can be still `null`, while it clearly cannot:

```
11: .map(({ foo }) => foo);
            ^ property `foo`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly null value
```

See the code on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AMVrKALygDeiookBAXKAM4oBOAlgHYDmiAvsgMaw2jUACMAhkzoBBJkzFoAPAH58sAHzFQAbVBsArtGgAaMlVqgA5AEU9ADwuhuoALr9Bw8QC9N4phVAAdJAs0ChYTAAUtsQa0QCERCT6hgCU-gEAtmIYERGk1LDcKTFmsCkA3EA).

Is there a way to tell flow that the array includes only non-nullable items now?

This destroys my functional JavaScript programming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Quick answer**

Use `.filter(Boolean)` to filter `null`'s.

```
const baz = bar
  .filter(Boolean) // <- This is the trick
  .map(({ foo }) => foo);
```

Check it passing on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AMVrKALygDeiookBAXKAM4oBOAlgHYDmiAvsgMaw2jUACMAhkzoBBJkzFoAPAH58sAHzFQAbVBsArtGgAaMlVqgA5AEU9ADwuhuoALr9Bw8QC9N4phVAAdJAs0ChYTAAUAEIE0FhibACU-gEAtmIYERGk1LDcicQauYkA3EA).

**Explanation** (sort of)

It is difficult for flow to understand what happens in the `filter` callback, how the result was obtained, and if really all `null` values were removed. Therefore it assumes that the type of array is the same after filtering; which in fact is correct, it can only be a subset of the array and hence a subset of the type.

In contrast, because of the way it works, `reduce` creates a totally different structure for which type has to be inferred ([flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AMVrKALygDeiookBAXKAM4oBOAlgHYDmiAvsgMaw2jUACMAhkzoBBJkzFoAPAH58sAHzFQAbVBsArtGgAaMlVqgA5AEU9ADwuhuoALr9Bw8QC9N4phVAAdExYACZ6fFgAFJEYwQBuJmxYtigAlMQaSSnEJPqGoEqgsVhxoHRaAZXFCbrJKM4mWs6p-gEAtmIY0aTUsNzpRBq9qQDcQA)):

```
const baz = bar
  .reduce((prev, next) => next == null ? prev : [...prev, next], [])
  .map(({foo}) => foo);
```

However, this use case is so common that flow includes an exception in [its code](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/core.js#L192):

```
filter(callbackfn: typeof Boolean): Array<$NonMaybeType<T>>;
filter(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: $ReadOnlyArray<T>) => any, thisArg?: any): Array<T>;
```

That means, that if (and only if) `Boolean` is passed as the callback the resulting array will have type `Array<$NonMaybeType<T>>`. `Boolean` will surely remove `null` (and `undefined`) and can be trusted.

Comment: It works in _this_ case, but it removes all "falsy" values. The same things with an array of strings would remove empty strings too for example, and don't even try to process an array of booleans with `undefined` values... :-) It's a shame really that Flow does not comprehend even a simple `===` (or an `instanceof`) comparison as a filter function.

Comment: The inability for flow to infer a simple `===` within `array.filter` basically makes flow unusable. Forcing the use of unreadable `array.reduce`. Why have filter if we have to do this?